# sorting 3 BST to one array in O(n) time and O(1) extra space

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write an algorithm for this problem:

> Merge three binary search trees into one sorted array, using O(n) time and O(1) additional space.

I think the straightforward answer is to do an in-order traversal of all three trees at once and compare the elements while traversing. But how can I do such a traversal in all three trees at once? Especially when the trees don't all have the same number of elements.

Comment: Does "O(1) in place" in the header actually mean "O(1) additional space"?

Comment: @Gassa
yes, sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea seems right.
In each tree, maintain a pointer (iterator).
Initially, the iterator should point to the leftmost node of the tree.

In every iteration, select the minimum of the elements under the three current pointers (it is O(1) time and memory).
Then put that minimum into the resulting array.
After that, advance the corresponding pointer so that it points to the leftmost unvisited element of the tree.
To be able to do that in O(1) memory, the tree should allow some way to go to this next unvisited element: it is sufficient to have a pointer to parent in each node.

Proceed with such iterations until all nodes are visited.

The traversal of a whole tree of n elements takes O(n) time: there are n-1 edges, and the process moves twice along each edge, once up and once down.
So the resulting complexity is 3*O(n) = O(n).

---

The algorithm to find the next unvisited node is as follows.
Note that, when we are at a node, its left subtree is already fully visited.
The steps are as follows:

1. While there is no unvisited right child, go up to the parent once.
   If, in doing so, we went up and right (we were at the left child), stop right there at the parent.
   If we were at the root, terminate the traversal.
2. Assuming we did not stop yet, there's a right child.
   Go there.
   Then while there's a left child, go to the left child.
   Stop.

The best way to grasp it is perhaps to visualize the steps on some non-trivial picture of a binary search tree. For example, there are explanatory pictures at the Wikipedia article on [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: The part that I don't understand how to do is once I set an element in the array, I need to find the successor of this element in the tree  (the next element in the in-order travel) so that finding all the elements in the tree will be take linear time. I see that you mentioned "advance the corresponding pointer so that it points to the leftmost unvisited element of the tree", but this is exactly the point in which I struggled to find out who to do this using  parent of each node.

Comment: @Mr.OY Added a part to the answer explaining the traversal algorithm. It is usually described with a stack, but that's more than O(1) additional memory. If on the other hand we have parents recorded at the nodes, the traversal can be O(1).

Comment: I don't think that having a parent pointer qualifies as O(1) space. It is possible to solve the problem _without_ a parent pointer: flatten each tree, and then merge the resulting lists (flattening is O(n) time, O(1) space).

Comment: @user58697 (1) Are you really sure we can flatten in O(n) *without a stack* to call some function recursively? Please share the idea then! But if not, stack is not O(1). (2) On the other side, depending on the context, parent pointers can be seen as an integral part of the tree, not something generated for the traversal exclusively. (3) For example, C++ red-black tree iterators do it without maintaining a stack. I don't know for sure but find it likely they store and use the parent pointer.

Comment: Absolutely so. It is a very well known technique. Check [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/discuss/37010/Share-my-simple-NON-recursive-solution-O(1)-space-complexity!) out, for example. The downside of course is that a tree structure is irrecoverably lost.

Comment: @user58697 Ah alright, thanks! If we reuse the two child pointers, I readily believe it's possible.